# Optimizing the total sum of weighted intervals

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have M intervals on the real line, each with a positive weight. I need to select N among them such that they don't overlap and give the maximum sum. How can I do that efficiently ?

If there is no subset of N non-overlapping intervals, there is no solution.

Without the non-overlap constraint, the question is trivial: pick the N largest weights. Because of the constraint, this doesn't work anymore. In my case, N and M are small (<20), but I hope that there is a more efficient solution than exhaustively trying all subsets.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: besides the fact that I a missing the required tools and skills, will that take care of the computational efficiency of the solution ?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: do these tools optimize for computational complexity ? And do they build algorithms at all ? Following PaulHankin, there is certainly a polynomial-time solution.

Comment: "if you have a specialised algorithm for solving your problem, go for it": I am asking for one. In my opinion, *SMT* would be a sledgehammer to *miss* flies here.

Comment: @PatrickTrentin: is the tag 'algorithm' enough ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can solve it with dynamic programming. Let `C(k, i)` be the maximum sum of (up to) `k` weighted intervals, none of which has their left end less than `i`.

You can restrict `i` to be in the set of (real) start points for all the intervals, and `k` ranges from `0` to `N`.

- Start by initializing `C(k, max(start for start, end in interval))` to `0`, and all other entries to -infinity.
- Sort the intervals by start points, and iterate through them backwards.
- For each interval (`start`, `end`) with weight `w`, and for each `k`:

  `C(start, k) = max(C(start, k), C(next(start), k), w + C(next'(end), k-1))`

Here `next(x)` returns the smallest start point greater than x, and `next'(x)` returns the smallest start point greater than or equal to `x`. Both can be implemented by binary search (or linear scan if M is small).

Overall, this is going to take O(M*N*logM) time and O(M*N) space.

(This assumes the intervals aren't closed at both ends, so (0, 100) and (100, 200) don't overlap -- a small adjustment needs to be made if these are to be considered overlapping).

Comment: I am buying that, thanks. They key is a recurrence on abscissa and interval count I guess. I'll accept the answer when I am sure to have well understood it. :)

Comment: I think the time complexity needs an M*log M term to account for sorting the M intervals.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The time should have been O(MNlogM) rather than O(MNlogN) as written. Now that I've fixed that, the extra MlogM term isn't needed.

Comment: O(MNlogM) is certainly correct, but I think it's looser than necessary, since f(M, N) = O(MNlogN + MlogM) implies f(M, N) = O(MNlogM) but AFAICT not the other way around.  (Assuming 1 <= N <= M, O(M(NlogN + logM)) = O(M(NlogM + logM)) = O(M(N+1)logM) = O(MNlogM), but in the other direction we can't just change logM to logN.)

Comment: @j_random_hacker what you say is correct, but the original O(MNlogN) was a mistake. The algorithm does binary search inside the full list of intervals (of size M), so logN was a mistake -- it should always have been logM. That it also fixes the issue you brought up was a lucky coincidence :)

Answer (score 0):

**In progress**:

Inspired by @PaulHankin's solution, here is a reformulation.

Sort all intervals by increasing right abscissa and iteratively find the largest possible sum up to the K-th right bound. Assume you have solved all optimization problems for the first K intervals and for all relevant N (from 0 to K).

When you take the next interval into consideration, you compute new candidate solutions as follows: for every N (up to the current nomber of intervals), lengthen all previous solutions that you can (including the empty one) without causing overlap, and keep the lenghtened solutions that are better.

Example:

[image]

The optimal sums up to the K-th right bound, by increasing N are

```
1: 2
2: 2 or 8 => 8 | -
3: 8 or 3 => 8 | 2 + 3                   | -
4: 8 or 2 => 8 | 2 + 3 or 8 + 2 => 8 + 2 | 2 + 3 + 2 | -
5: 8 or 9 => 9 | 8 + 2 or 2 + 9 => 2 + 9 | 2 + 3 + 2 | - | -
```